# Render dust tag as plain html

Tags: dust.js

I am making a documentation page in dust.js.

Part of the documentation is to show the partial code without it being rendered.

I have tried to make a helper for this

`{dust}
   {@partial}...{/partial}
 {dust}`

But this doesn't seem to be the right approach.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Part of the documentation is to show the partial code without it being
>   rendered.

You should replace `{` and `}` by `{~lb}` and `{~rb}` so they are not parsed by Dust

Comment: what i mean is to show {@partial}...{/partial} as is and not include it the partial. (as text)

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your question.
You should replace `{` and `}` with `{~lb}` and `{~rb}` so they are not parsed by Dust

Comment: ahh cool thanks - works, if you change your answer I will accept